# What is the "(x)" term in macro

Tags: c, macros

I found a structure definition as shown below,

```
#define MAX_SIZE(x) 1

struct var
{

    int temp;
    int temp2[MAX_SIZE(temp)];

};
```

What does `MAX_SIZE(temp)` mean?.

What is the dimension of `temp2` array?.

Comment: the parameter is unused... that's a damn good misleading macro. Try `MAX_SIZE(whatever)`

Comment: Where did you find this? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the intention here is to document which field of the structure governs the actual size of a [flexible array member](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18).  Since C provides no way to tell the compiler the actual size of a flexible array member, it's intentional that `MAX_SIZE` ignores its argument, because the C compiler can't make any use of the information.  It's just for human readers.  (This *should have* been explained in documentation comments above the definition of `MAX_SIZE`.)

Whoever wrote the code is confusing the issue by using the *really* old notation for flexible array members: neither the C99 sanctioned syntax `temp2[]` nor the older GNU extension `temp2[0]`, but the way you wrote it in the days of [pcc](http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/), `temp2[1]`.  Are you looking at the source code to a very old program? Is it still using [old-style function definitions](https://jameshfisher.com/2016/11/27/c-k-and-r/) perchance?

Anyway, you should understand the definition of `struct var` as being

```
struct var
{
    int temp;
    int temp2[temp];
};
```

... in the counterfactual version of C in which you can actually write that, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you are curious what the preprocessor is doing, your compiler can generate the preprocessed file for you.  For example, compile this with `gcc -E try.c -o try.i` and take a look at the output.

This fragment is small enough you can just do `gcc -E try.c`, but in general if you include anything the preprocessed output can get quite long.

This macro is pretty useless:  anything you give it resolves to 1